# How to prove that: $\int_\Bbb R f(x)dx = \int_\Bbb R f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, change-of-variable

Let $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ How can I prove that: $$\int_\Bbb R f(x)dx = \int_\Bbb R f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx$$

In fact the changes of variables $u=\phi(x) = x-\frac{1}{x}$ seems correct but the image of zero : $\phi(0)$ does not exists.

How can I avoid this issues? thanks

Comment: This result goes back to Cauchy and a generalization is due to Glasser (Glasser, M. L. "A Remarkable Property of Definite Integrals." Math. Comput. 40, 561-563, 1983. ). See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html Note that it has to be interpreted in a principal value to be true in general

Comment: The trick is the change of variable $x = 1/y$ to obtain $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\frac1y-y)\frac{dy}{y^2}$
and to note with $F'(x) = f(x)$ that $\int_a^b f(x-\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx = F(x-\frac{1}{x})|_a^b$.

Comment: @GuyFsone "$\phi(0)$ does not exists" is a nonsense. $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx = \lim_{n \to 0} \int_{1/n}^n g(x)dx$ and the change of variable you mentioned works fine,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result (and a generalisation) is proved by [Glasser](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf), I transcribe the first part here following the notation in the original post.

From a graph of the relation $\phi = x - 1/x$, one sees that the solution for $x$ has two branches
$$x_\pm = \frac{1}{2} \left(\phi \pm \sqrt{\phi^2 + 4}\right), \quad -\infty < \phi < \infty.$$
Thus 
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\phi) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0^-} f(\phi) \, dx_- + \int_{0^+}^{-\infty} f(\phi) \, dx_+=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\phi) (x_-'+x_+')\, d\phi.$$
But $$x_-' + x_+' = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\phi^2+4}}+1 + \frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\phi^2+4}}\right) = 1.$$